# Vertices Select Highlighting Not Consistent With Rigging

Tags: armature, vertices, weight-painting

I have a mesh of a deer that I am getting ready to do weight painting with. I'm following a tutorial that does it through selecting vertices. I selected the bone for the head and vertices for half the body get selected.
[image]

I deselected the vertices I don't need to show what I want it to be.
[image]

Is there any way to select vertices and then assign them to a bone for later use?

Answer (score 1):

Bones assignements are strictly related to vertex groups:  if you animate a bone named "Head", Blender will search for a vertex group named "Head", as it finds it he will move all the vertices accordingly to every single vertex weight.
So you can select your character, select the armature, Ctrl P for parenting them, then choose the option "with empty group": this will create an empty vertex group named as every bone of the armature: then you can select a group of vertices, go to the vertex tab on the properties menu, select the "Head" vertex group, choose the weight you want with the slider, and click the assign button. 
Note also that in the "N" properties panel of the 3D window, if you select a vertex in edit mode you can read all his weights assignements.

[image]

Comment: Might want to add that it might be necessary to remove vertices from the grop as well, and that all vertices assigned to the group (including those with zero weight can be selected with the 'select' button).

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding on one of our parts. I know how to do weight painting in vertex mode, BUT if I select the head the whole body gets selected and then I have to deselect a bunch of vertices so that I can paint the head. How do I make it so that only the vertices around the head are selected when I select the head?

Comment: Are you using the "select" button in vertex groups tab, or wich other way?